# dictionary Is extracting the wrong values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, binary-search

I am having issues with python dictionary, currently, I am trying to implement a binary search algorithm without using extensions, and I am stuck, the function could only extract the last middle items, it cannot extract the first and last items. Here are my codes:

object

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,packageName,customerName,numberOfPax,packagePaxPerCost):
    self.__packageName = packageName
    self.__customerName = customerName
    self.__numberOfPax = numberOfPax
    self.__packagePaxPerCost = packagePaxPerCost

    def get_packageName(self):
        return self.__packageName

    def get_customerName(self):
        return self.__customerName

    def get_numberOfPax(self):
        return self.__numberOfPax

    def get_packagePaxPerCost(self):
        return self.__packagePaxPerCost


    def set_packageName(self,packageName):
        self.__packageName = packageName

    def set_customerName(self,customerName):
        self.__customerName = customerName

    def set_numberOfPax(self,numberOfPax):
        self.__numberOfPax = numberOfPax

    def set_packagePaxPerCost(self,packagePaxPerCost):
        self.__packagePaxPerCost = packagePaxPerCost
```

dictionary items

```
Records_dict = {}
############################ Dummy Data #############################
Records1 = Customer('normal suite 2', 'Bobby', '1', '100')
Records_dict[Records1.get_customerName()] = Records1

Records2 = Customer('normal suite 4', 'Tommy', '30', '400')
Records_dict[Records2.get_customerName()] = Records2

Records3 = Customer('normal suite 1', 'Johny', '10','500')
Records_dict[Records3.get_customerName()] = Records3

Records4 = Customer('normal suite 3', 'Jimmy', '20', '300')
Records_dict[Records4.get_customerName()] = Records4

Records5 = Customer('normal suite 4', 'Jim', '90','900')
Records_dict[Records5.get_customerName()] = Records5

#####################################################################
```

selection sort algorithm

```
def selectionSort(entries):
    list2 = []
    sortedDict = {}
    for eachitem in entries.values():
        list2.append(eachitem.get_customerName())

    n = len(list2)
    for eachitem2 in range(n-1):
        smallestNumber = eachitem2


    for j in range(eachitem2+1, n):
        if entries[list2[j]].get_packageName().lower() < entries[list2[smallestNumber]].get_packageName().lower():
            smallestNumber = j

    if smallestNumber != eachitem2:
        tmp = entries[list2[eachitem2]]
        entries[list2[eachitem2]] = entries[list2[smallestNumber]]
        entries[list2[smallestNumber]] = tmp

    return entries
```

binary search algorithm

```
def binarySearch(target, entries2):
    entries = selectionSort(entries2)
    list = []

    for eachItem in entries.values():
        list.append(eachItem.get_customerName())
    print(list)

    low = 0

    list2  = []
    high = len(list)-1
    print(entries[list[0]].get_packageName())
    while low <= high:

        mid = (high+low)//2
        print(entries[list[0]].get_packageName())
        print(entries2[list[mid]].get_packageName())
        if entries2[list[mid]].get_packageName().lower() == target.lower():
            customerName = entries[list[mid]].get_customerName()
            packageName = entries[list[mid]].get_packageName()
            numberOfPax = entries[list[mid]].get_numberOfPax()
            packagePaxPerCost = entries[list[mid]].get_packagePaxPerCost()
            list2.append([packageName, customerName, numberOfPax, packagePaxPerCost])
            return list2



        elif target.lower() < entries[list[mid]].get_packageName().lower():
            high = mid - 1

        else:

            low = mid + 1

    list2 = []
    if list2 == []:
        print('blank')

    return list2

test = binarySearch('normal suite 2',Records_dict)
print(test)
```

Comment: Your `selectionSort` does not sort anything, at the very most it switches exactly two items once. Debug and fix that code first. Why do you iterate `eachitem2`, why do you use it after the loop again, why not just `smallestNumber = n-2`?

Comment: An unrelated side note: here you can find a short intro to [getters and setters in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-in-python/).